# LOOOOONG TEEEEEXT

Tags: code-golf, string

### Definition of long text

Long text usually **shows emphasis**, for instance, `loooooool` or `yaaaaaaaaaay`. Usually the vowel is replicated many times. In this challenge we require:

- At least 3 times, which means `yaaay` and `yaaaay` are allowed, but `yay` and `yaay` are not.
- Consistent, which means that shoes can turn out be `shoooeees` or `shooooeeees` but not `shoooeeees` or `shooooeees`. Of course, it seems that no one would do that, however, this is to reinforce the next law.
- Undoubling, which means `beeping` turns out to be `beeepiiing` or `beeeepiiiing` but not `beeeeeepiiing` or `beeeeeeeepiiiing`. This is not the case for long text, but such makes this challenge non-trivial.
- Thus, the long text **might** turn out shorter than the original text, that is, `aaaaa` can turn out to be `aaa`.

### Your challenge

#### Input

Your input will be a sentence, that is, you may **not** assume there are only words. We do **not** guarantee all will be English words, so look out for `theeeeeeeeese`.

#### Output

The long text for the input.

### Test cases

**We assume you repeat 3 times**.

`The fox yawns...`  => `Theee fooox yaaawns...`

`Everything is good!!!!!`  => `Eeeveeerythiiing iiis goood!!!!!`  and **NOT** `EEEveeerythiiing iiis gooooood!!!!!`

`Eeny, meeny, miny, moe` => `Eeeeeeny, meeeny, miiiny, moooeee`

`AAARGH` => `AaaRGH`

`Weeeeeeeeheeeeeee` => `Weeeheee`

**Note the treatment of capital letters**: The first letter remains capital, and the others are lowered. `eE` will be `eeeEee`, they won't be the same. "Undoubling" only happens for letters which are of the same case (like `ee` or `AA`, but not for `Ee`)

**Only the letters from `a`, `e`, `i`, `o`, and `u` are vowels, case insensitive**.

Comment: "laugh out out out out out out out out out out loud" is an interesting way of expressing amusement ;-).

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but shouldn't `yay` as input result in `yyyaaayyy`?

Comment: Only the letters from a, e, i, o, and u are vowels, case insensitive. @LarsKristensen

Comment: For test case 3, should "Eeeeeeny" be "Eeeny"? Or are the capitals treated separately?

Comment: Shouldn't we be looking out for `theeeeeseeeee`?

Answer (score 17):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 10 bytes

```
ĠƛhA[h:d⇩+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJkIiwiIiwixKDGm2hBW2g6ZOKHqSsiLCIiLCJIRWNrayJd)

Nice simple answer.

### Explained

```
ĠƛhA[h:d⇩+
Ġƛ         # to each group of consecutive characters: 
  hA       #   is the character a vowel?
    [      #   if so:
     h:d   #     Push the character and a string with two copies of that character
        ⇩+ #     and add the lowercase version of that to the character. 
# The -d flag flattens all sublists to depth 1 and then sums the list.
```

Comment: YOu are only supposed to capitalize the vowel if it is capitalized i.e. This -> Thiiis

Comment: OK this is now good.

Comment: hDA and then no h: I think (on mobile)

Comment: @emanresuA that doesn't account for duplicate consonants

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 29 bytes

Now handles undoubling thanks to [@Jo King]!

```perl
s/((?i)[aeiou])\1*/$1\L$1$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YX0PDPlMzOjE1M780VjPGUEtfxTDGR8VQxVA//f//kIxUhbT8CoXKxPK8Yj09PS7XstSiypKMzLx0hcxihfT8/BRFEOByTc2r1FHITYVQmWAyP5Ur1ZXLKTW1AKgcpDkRBfzLLyjJzM8r/q9bAAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
ŒgµŒlṁ3fØcȯaẆḢ)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opPRDW49Oynm4s9E47fCM5BPrEx/uanu4Y5Hm/4e7txxuf9S0JvL//5CMVIW0/AqFysTyvGI9PT0FLtey1KLKkozMvHSFzGKF9Pz8FEUQAEqk5lXqKOSmQqhMMJmfyuXo6Bjk7sEVngoFGVCaK5ErEYjyuVxduVJJA7kgQykAoUAHAQA)

```
Œgµ           )    For each run of consecutive equal elements:
   Œl              Lowercase it,
     ṁ3            mold it to length 3,
       fØc         remove non-vowels,
          ȯ        and substitute the original run if that left it empty.
           aẆḢ     Fix the capitalization:
           a       vectorizing logical AND with
            Ẇ      each sublist of the run, individually
           a       because of something to do with how vectorization handles depth?
             Ḣ     and take the head of the resulting list.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 78 bytes

```
lambda s:re.sub(r"([aeiouAEIOU])\1*",lambda m:m[1]+2*m[1].lower(),s)
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3_XISc5NSEhWKrYpS9YpLkzSKlDSiE1Mz80sdXT39Q2M1Ywy1lHSginKtcqMNY7WNtECUXk5-eWqRhqZOsSZXZm5BflGJQlEq1NTYgqLMvBKNNA0lx5wc9WKF8tScHIWSjMQShdS8FBAXBJQ0Nbng6lxT8yp1FHJTIVQmmMxHVeLo6Bjk7gEUgliyYAGEBgA)

I don't read Perl unless under duress, but if would I'd have to note that this looks very similar to @Dom Hastings' answer.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), 63 bytes

Repeats 3 times.

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/([AEIOUaeiou])\1*/g,([c])=>c+(c+c).toLowerCase())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYrRCoIwGEbve4rl1ZY16QEUJKSCIIiiC/NizF9d2H7ZTPPprcCrWOfmg/Odu@iElUY17UpjDmMRjjaMLDfQ1EICDWgaJ/vjRYDCZ8Zu60VQLmkqMxZG0qfSl4y3eMAezEZYoIyNErXFGniNJS2od66AFPgig@i15Zx7jM1@kqQDM7SV0iVRlpSI@fyLqwQ9OPQD/njl1ggOG8fxabtzHFeYqKb9NOMb)

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>28</s> bytes

```
((?i)[aeiou])\1*
$1$l$1$l$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0PDPlMzOjE1M780VjPGUItLxVAlB4L//w/JSFVIy69QqEwszyvW09Pjci1LLaosycjMS1fILFZIz89PUQQBLtfUvEodhdxUCJUJJvNTuVJduZxSUwuAykGaE1EAAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: Port of @DomHastings' Perl answer, but Retina's `$l` operator only operates on the next token, so either as here it has to be repeated for each token to be lowercased or the letters need to be grouped `$1$l$($1$1` which here happens to be the same length as the group does not need to be explicitly closed. Unfortunately Retina's repetition operator does not help here as `$12*$l$1` parses as `${12}*$($l$1)` so the best we can do is `${1}2*$l$1` which is still the same length. Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @DomHastings by porting his `(?i)` golf from his answer.

Comment: Ah.. No wonder I couldn't find `$l`! I was accidentally looking in the Retina 0.8.2 docs for the word 'lower', instead of the latest Retina version.. :/ I'll change my answer to 0.8.2, although I have the feeling it can still be golfed perhaps.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Your answer? Oh, right, you answered in between me loading the page and answering. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I've just remembered about `(?i)` since the match is in a capturing group, that can save you another byte (I wonder if there's also a builtin flag for these in Retina?): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/X0PDPlMzOjE1M780VjPGUItLxVAlB4L//w/JSFVIy69QqEwszyvW09Pjci1LLaosycjMS1fILFZIz89PUQQBLtfUvEodhdxUCJUJJvNTuVJduZxSUwuAykGaE1EAAA "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: @DomHastings Nice! I don't know what you mean about a builtin flag though, since it's only the group itself that can be case insensitive, not the backreference. (Also, you accidentally broke one of the links when you edited your answer.)

Comment: No worries! I guess I wondered if there was (for example) a character in Retina's codepage that compiled to `(?i)` (and the other flags) but I guess that's not the case. Not sure it's especially useful though, I guess things like `$&`, `$1`, `\1`, ``T` `` being single chars would be more useful so they'd probably be a higher priority to exist... Golf isn't the point of Retina though, so I guess it's not priority. It would probably be trivial to add a wrapper language that supports that kind of thing if it was desired but I digress...

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
γεDlžMÃĀiÙDlDJ]J
```

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because [there is a bug in the new version with `Ā` (Python-style truthify builtin) on empty strings `""`, incorrectly giving a truthy result instead of falsey](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/issues/189).

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3OZzW11yju7zPdx8pCHz8EyXHBevWK///5WUlEIyUhXS8isUKhPL84r19PS4XMtSiypLMjLz0hUyixXS8/NTFEGAyzU1r1JHITcVQmWCyfxULkdHxyB3D67wVCjIgNJcqa5A0wE)

**Explanation:**

```python
γ              # Split the (implicit) input-string into parts of equal adjacent
               # characters
 ε             # Map over each part:
  D            #  Duplicate the current part
   l           #  Lowercase the copy
    žM         #  Push the vowels constant "aeiou"
      Ã        #  Only keep those characters from the lowercase copy
       Āi      #  If it's non-empty (thus a part with vowels):
         Ù     #   Uniquify to a single character
          D    #   Duplicate it
           l   #   Lowercase the copy
            D  #   Duplicate that again
             J #   Join the three characters together
 ]             # Close the if-statement and map
  J            # Join everything back together
               # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>82</s> <s>80</s> 79 bytes

```
lambda s,*e:''.join([c,(c+2*c.lower())*(e!=c)][(e:=c)in"AEIOUaeiou"]for c in s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY69CsJAEIR7n2JNk7sYr7ASwSKFqFVAFAu1iOeeOdFbyY8xL2JjExB9J9_GaIKgU-wHM8My18cxT0IyxU31l_c0Ue3u098Hh_UmgNh1sGfbYkfasIV0mWx1HCn2lGHEOHcYNvuSrxYMeyW1sbzB2J8FqCm1VooikKANxLx-ezlG2iRMMWsaIig6Qx5kJhZCgMV545sOThiVm7TZgo5hS7RpvvVXQpO7cMAK-nMJfyqe502Gox9rjrXCmmVarSuKii8)
First time realising that you can use the walrus operator (`:=`) in list comprehension to store the previous value of the iterable. Just needs to be initialised

-1 byte thanks to @Unrelated String

Comment: You can save 1 by rearranging into a recursive function: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY69CsIwFIV3n-LaKdFa1EkKGTqIOomiONQOMb2xAU2kqT99EReXgug7-Tb-tAh6hvvBOYfLudx3eZYYXVwlW972mWz1HhPJNny7ijlYF1nbt8B1HAqf2bAduUQ0uw3hbcwRU0Jpg2CdCRqFApR2gv5oPOeozN6JmpLYsONHrqDV4_MuVTojkjizBEGaE-T8qK3neeBQWvum_QOmr1VKr0FZWBsT19_6K6HOXdhiCfW5Bn8qQRBMB8Mfa4GVkoqvtFxXFCWf

Comment: @loopywalt thanks, but just realised I could lose 2 bytes by getting rid of the outer list

Comment: [unfortunately 1 byte shorter :(](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY69CsJAEIR7n2JN412MV1iJkCKFqJUoikVMEc89c6K3ksSfvIiNTUD0nXwbowmCTrEfzAzLXB_7LI3I5DflLu6HVLU6z_E23C1XISSOjd1GQ2xIG-b70mGy2bal2NIJY8a5zbDuSh74DLsFtbG83nA0C1HTwQoUxSBBG0gCXj2-7GNtUqaYNY0QFJ0hC08mEUKAxXntm_aOGBertFmDTmBNtKq_9VdCkzmwwxL6cwl_Kp7nTfqDH2uOlaKKRVquy_OSLw)

Comment: @UnrelatedString [actually you can knock 2 bytes off yours for a total of 79](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY69CsJAEIR7n2JNk7sYr7ASwSKFqFVAFAu1iOeeOdFbyY8xL2JjExB9J9_GaIKgU-wHM8My18cxT0IyxU31l_c0Ue3u098Hh_UmgNh1sGfbYkfasIV0mWx1HCn2lGHEOHcYNvuSrxYMeyW1sbzB2J8FqCm1VooikKANxLx-ezlG2iRMMWsaIig6Qx5kJhZCgMV545sOThiVm7TZgo5hS7RpvvVXQpO7cMAK-nMJfyqe502Gox9rjrXCmmVarSuKii8)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 23 bytes

```
ṁ?oS:oR2_←Iȯ€"AEIOU"a←g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8f/DnY32@cFW@UFG8Y/aJnieWP@oaY2So6unf6hSIlAg/f///9FKIRmpCmn5FQqVieV5xXp6eko6Sq5lqUWVJRmZeekKmcUK6fn5KYogAJJJzavUUchNhVCZYDI/FSjh6OgY5O4BZISnQkEGlAaK@WYWF4NQQUGmUiwA)

```
ṁ?oS:oR2_←Iȯ€"AEIOU"a←g
                      g # group identical adjacent letters   
ṁ                       # and, for each group, do this and combine the results:
  ?                     # if
                     ←  # the first element
                    a   # in uppercase form                    
           ȯ€"AEIOU"    # is one of "AEIOU"
         ←              # then get the first element,
        _               # lowercase it,
      R2                # duplicate it,
   S:o                  # and add that to itself;
          I             # otherwise leave the group unchanged
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
r"(%v)%1*"Ï+²v
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ciIoJXYpJTEqIs8rsnY&input=WwoiVGhlIGZveCB5YXducy4uLiIKIkV2ZXJ5dGhpbmcgaXMgZ29vZCEhISEhIgoiRWVueSwgbWVlbnksIG1pbnksIG1vZSIKIkFBQVJHSCIKIldlZWVlZWVlZWhlZWVlZWVlIgpdLW1S) (Includes all test cases)

```
r"(%v)%1*"Ï+²v     :Implicit input of string
r                  :Replace
 "(%v)%1*"         :Regex /([AEIOUaeiou])\1*/g
          Ï        :Pass the first submatch (i.e., the first character in the match) through the following function
           +       :Append
            ²      :The character duplicated
             v     :And lowercased
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `grouping.extras math.unicode sequences.repeating`, <s>119</s> <s>111</s> <s>109</s> <s>102</s> <s>100</s> 95 bytes

```factor
[ [ ] group-by values [ dup "aeiouAEIOU"⊂ [ 3 cycle 1 cut >lower append ] when ] map-concat ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RVC7TsNAEBSi81csrrElRINAQnIRhTQgARGFFaHNeROfsG-PeySxEA0lv0CTBj6Bf4GSL-Gsc5Rp5nZnNLt7H18LFI7N9vfgcHo3uR6fAxqDnYWlYa-lWua0cQYtoLUsLDyRUdSApWdPSpANL2fBKym4ImjR1fmK-kS79-wiJEfDzr03GNKELkyDiyR5SSAgva8JFryBDtfK5nmexvZoRaZzde-VYUvm6qjHTiXVHUNLkaSinpgGtSiK2_HVUDzQgHrgNHn99G6Rnf08llDCLH5BNu9ghY0Pp5ZQeQ0pkmRfjCY30_Tv_S10T0F0oiE4AeEdXDa8JgOoNakqpKxrUoFa1JlgJdDBLI75LkEbqUINglvNloBQ1FHcbiP_Aw)

Unfortunately Factor's regular expressions are very limited by design so they can't be used to help much. This is still maybe quite golfable regardless.

- `[ ] group-by values` Break the input into groups of contiguous equal characters.
- `[ ... ] map-concat` Map each group to a sequence, all of which get concatenated together in the end.
- `dup "aeiouAEIOU"⊂` Is it a group of vowels?
- `[ 3 cycle 1 cut >lower append ] when` Make it length three and 'capitalize' it if so. (i.e. "aaa" -> "aaa", "AAA" -> "Aaa")

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>63</s> <s>47</s> 43 bytes

```
([AEIOUaeiou])\1*
$1$1$1
rT`L`l`\1([AEIOU])
```

<s>This can definitely be shorter..</s> It can, see [*@Neil*'s Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247524/52210). My answer uses the older version, which didn't had builtin `$l` yet (nor `$1$1$1` to `3*$1`).
<s>I again have the feeling this can be shorter..</s> And it can: -16 bytes thank to *@Neil*, and I've been able to golf it slightly more.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fI9rR1dM/NDE1M780VjPGUItLxRAEuYpCEnwSchJiDKEqYjX//w/JSFVIy69QqEwszyvW09Pjci1LLaosycjMS1fILFZIz89PUQQBLtfUvEodhdxUCJUJJvNTuRwdHYPcPbjCU6EgA0pzpbqmckW6OnoAAA)

**Explanation:**

Get all consecutive matches of 1 or more of the same vowels, and shorten/extend them to three of these vowels:

```
([AEIOUaeiou])\1*
$1$1$1
```

Lowercase every match of two adjacent uppercase vowels by transliterating in reverse order:

```
rT`L`l`\1([AEIOU])
```

Comment: Your last step doesn't work for the test case of `AAARGH` (it lowercases the `R`) but it also fails for e.g. `YEAH` (should be `YEeeAaaH`).

Comment: @Neil Can regex lookaheads/behinds be used for the transliterate regex? Or can the transliterate limit not be applied to the entire string, but only to each individual match? Or can we apply the transliterate in a reverse order to the string?

Comment: @Neil [This works](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fI9rR1dM/NDE1M780VjPGUItLxRAEuUISfBJyEqDSIBkujWiIqmqjWk0NPU0uFSMVw///QzJSFdLyKxQqE8vzivX09Lhcy1KLKksyMvPSFTKLFdLz81MUQYDLNTWvUkchNxVCZYLJ/FQuR0fHIHcPrvBUKMiA0lyprlyRro4eAA), but is even longer.. :/ I would like to apply the `r` (RightToLeft) mode to the transliterate somehow..

Comment: The second limit applies to each individual match of a transliteration, so you can write ``0T1>`L`l`([AEIOU])\1\1`` to transliterate all characters after the first of each match, thus saving a byte over my previous approaches of ``T`L`l`([AEIOU])\1(?!\1)`` and ``rT`L`l`(?<=\1)([AEIOU])``. But maybe you can combine the latter with your suggestion to get down to 42 bytes?

Comment: @Neil Ah, I had to put the `r` in front of it without tilde! I tried both `Tr` and ``r`T`` without any avail, haha. Thanks! And I've indeed been able to golf it slightly more to 43.

Comment: Whoops, yes, I miscounted, I had that very 43 byte solution in mind. (But `Tr` works; maybe your `\1` was in the wrong place at the time?)

Comment: @Neil You're right, my `\1` was indeed still after the (...), so that probably was the issue then.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>125</s> <s>121</s> 119 bytes

- -2 thanks to ceilingcat

Scans for vowels and coalesces duplicates, lowercasing the extra output vowels.

```c
i,c;f(char*s){for(;c=*s++;){if(index("aeiou",c|32)){for(;i=c==*s;s++);for(;i<3;)putchar(c|!!i++*32);}else putchar(c);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PVDPa8MgFL7nr3gRBmpsGOvROshhbOcx2GHsEIwmQqslmrYhzb@@zDRp3@F7fj@e@JSbWsppMkxyjWVTttSTQbsWcymozzJOBqOxsZW6YFQq4zrE5HX7QtaUEVLEII9Rwhdlt@Xk2IX5MiyvaWqyjMYBPqq9V/BwojBOxgY4lMbikzMVgSEBmF2g/udXzAwAfTUKtLtAX56tz/McsUV/O6m2D42xNRgPtXNVOtfDVrZncFBLMzd06u4WRfH5/nFn32qtZu2r8RxxZEBpiNDxJNJ5xyA8h07QEP9nXshjhMjyeoBjG5fSGD15EK@AGHSE3wyNl9OYjNOf1Puy9tPm/A8)

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 34 bytes

```
:%s/\v([aeiouAEIOU])\1*/\1\L\1\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/30q1WD@mTCM6MTUzv9TR1dM/NFYzxlBLP8YwxgeIDfXT//8PyUhVSMuvUKhMLM8r1tPT43ItSy2qLMnIzEtXyCxWSM/PT1EEAS7X1LxKHYXcVAiVCSbzU7kcHR2D3D24wlOhIANKAwA)

Very similar to other regex based solutions.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 29 bytes

```
ＦＳ¿¬⁼ιψ«ι≔ωψ¿№AEIOU↥ι«≔ιψ↧ι↧ι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBwzOvoLQkuKQoMy9dQ1NTITNNQcMvv0TDtbA0MadYI1NHoVITKFzNxRkAVFKikalpzcXpWFycmZ6nUQ6SBHJBepzzS4GySo6unv6hSjoKoQUFqUXJicWpQA0Q7TBNmVBNUPN88ssRCnEL13LV/v/v6OgY5O7xX7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＳ
```

Loop over the characters of the input string.

```
¿¬⁼ιψ«
```

If this is not a duplicate vowel, then:

```
ι
```

Output the current character.

```
≔ωψ
```

Clear the last duplicate vowel.

```
¿№AEIOU↥ι«
```

If this is a vowel, then:

```
≔ιψ
```

Store the last vowel.

```
↧ι↧ι
```

Output the lowercased vowel twice.

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>440</s> 428 bytes

```go
import(."regexp";."strings")
type S=string
func f(s S)S{M,Q,N,x:=MustCompile,Repeat,NewReplacer,`((?i)[aeiou]`
L:=[]S{}
for _,r:=range`AEIOU`{c:=S(r);l:=ToLower(c);L=append(L,Q(c,3),c,Q(c,2),c,Q(l,3),l,Q(l,2),l)}
R:=N(L...)
l:=R.Replace(s)
for;l!=s;l,s=R.Replace(l),l{}
return N([]S{"AAA","Aaa","EEE","Eee","III","Iii","OOO","Ooo","UUU","Uuu"}...).Replace(M(x+`)`).ReplaceAllString(M(x+`+)`).ReplaceAllString(l,"$1"),"$1$1$1"))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLditQwFMbbPEU2KCRsLKg30hKlSNGB-dmd7uDFONjQPe0UM01JWmeGMk_izSB45wv4Br6CPo1JOy5emMJ3Dt9Jz_mSL1--lvr8o5H5J1kC3smqRtWu0aYNSLFrybeuLZ6-_P3o-0jSgBgo4dCQKCC2NVVdWsJQe2wAp2IkUNHVOS6oxSlL-xm_5XN-CMWss-0bvWsqBXwJDciWz2HvMiVzMDyj9HXF1hIq3W0yNA3FepP2J1Rogz9yEwoj6xKyOJksVlmfhyKlhkUqFHd6qvdgaM6iqZBNA_U9nfJbmvMXjOdD8nxMlGfUkDhGsRNahmJOp0EQMOQ6LYOLGmqZnxupK2Ejxe0_FeV-dKoMtJ2p8Zx6kSSOY8JJLKXDJEk8AjicTCYeq8rhYrHwqLXD1WrlsevIyc9-aD6jh-uMZQ9ErFQ6XOlYuf5vSXHy-BlhHv1HGDuNpv36ORjhLaUM9yiXFiwOBV5vRqN6crcFXOgDPsp9bZ0UTDgmyWcwx3brNuDK4lLr-yu_xhrUR453MIZqQA2-4u5g-fadz97DZW0vkfx1cZg--IhHMT26cULagpLsic2weIV9_FC7Npb7J8QYOqHLec7nMf4B)

What no regex backtracking does to a mfer.

Looking at other answers, Golang lacks the following regex features that other answers are dependent on:

- Backtracking `(abc)\1`
- Lowercase mode `\L`

So, I've had to make do with a mix of regex and pure string replacement using `strings.Replacer`s to handle the lack of backtracking and lowercase mode.

#### Edits

- -12 bytes by moving the code for initializing the translation pairs for `R` out of the function.

#### Explanation

```go
import(."regexp";."strings") // boilerplate imports
type S=string                // alias string for byte saving
func f(s S)S{                // function of string to string
// define the following:
// - abbreviations for commonly-used functions
// - a partial shared regex
M,Q,N,x:=MustCompile,Repeat,NewReplacer,`((?i)[aeiou]`
// create a new replacer that maps "AAA"=>"A", "AA"=>"A", etc
R:=N(func()(L[]S){for _,r:=range`AEIOU`{c:=S(r);l:=ToLower(c);L=append(L,Q(c,3),c,Q(c,2),c,Q(l,3),l,Q(l,2),l)};return}()...)
// do the replacement...
l:=R.Replace(s)
// ...while the input hasn't changed
for;l!=s;l,s=R.Replace(l),l{}

return
// create another replacer, for the uppercase case
N([]S{"AAA","Aaa","EEE","Eee","III","Iii","OOO","Ooo","UUU","Uuu"}...).Replace(
// match `((?i)[aeiou])`...
    M(x+`)`).ReplaceAllString(
// replace (de-duplicated) vowels...
    M(x+`+)`).ReplaceAllString(l,"$1"),
// with 3 copies of the vowel 
    "$1$1$1"))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 59 bytes

```julia
!x=replace(x,r"((?i)[aeiou])\1*"=>i->i[1]lowercase(i[1]^2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBboMwEETv/orFJ7uiSPRYiVQcUHuuKuWQppKBTdjKtZEhCUj5d2qD2zl4d@bN@vuiSeXTsiRT4bDXqkExpY4L8ULyoJDs5Sg/8wde7OhxR4f8qO0NXaMGFMF9PUm5nKwDAjLgULWaDA5CMvBSaQ0FDL2mUVAKHIod8A31jsyojVAhS9QWJt4VUMP9/s95NfXYjNg@A0@hlgxNu3x0CCc7waxuZsiyLPzhMwypXXMVCauu6OaxI3MGGuBsbZsEhYsK8epvVkxrgbZK7LAKzZzCD26D1tdiPEX8oxFTLFjrI1aW5fvrW@iWSvmN7TGqizOwffS/)

sadly Julia doesn't seem to support `\l` or `\L`